# Replacing 32 bit 16.04 LTS with 64 bit 16.04 LTS

Tags: boot, 16.04, 64-bit

I have finally managed to back-up my system to prep for replacing 32 bit 16.04 LTS with 64 bit 16.04 LTS.

I created a clean USB boot drive to download the 64 bit version. I interrupt boot, go to the bios, instruct to load from a SanDisk 8GB Cruzer drive (which the system can see/identify), the system 'magenta screens' then starts to load.

After loading I check the settings and get told the 32 bit version is still running. Run `uname -a` and get this:

> Linux roland-desktop 3.13.0-61-generic #100-Ubuntu SMP Wed Jul 29 11:22:15 UTC 2015 i686 athlon i686 GNU/Linux

which confirms I am still running 32 bit,

The only file on the thumb drive is 'ubuntu-16.04.01-desktop-amd64.iso'

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: How do you create your boot stick? My best experiences are just using `sudo cp ubuntu.iso /dev/sdx`, where `x` is probably `b` but you can check with `sudo fdisk -l`

Comment: Have you used a utility to such as Startup Disk Creator to make the bootable USB, or did you just put the .iso file on to the drive?

Comment: Yes, I have Startup Disc Creator and used that. I am repeating using a different flash drive to see if that is the issue.

Comment: Seems to be working with the new drive - fingers crossed. Given that everyone on the net seems to say that the SD 8GB Cruzer works as a boot flash drive, I must have the duff one ....Story of my Linux life. Anyone one want a bet the back up crashes?

Comment: ...hope your backup works, good luck.

Comment: As `uname -a` is saying `Roland Desktop` I'm sure you booted to your normal desktop. Make the usb bootable using mkusb and use it to boot into Live mode. check the bios option

Comment: Cheers brother - and everyone else who chipped in to help. Much appreciated.